# Characterizing Conic Section By Eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, conic-sections, quadratic-forms, plane-curves

We can bring a function of the form 
$$ax^2+2bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$$

To the form of $$\lambda_{1}(x'')^2+\lambda_{2}(y'')^2+k=0$$
In a textbook It is written that if:

1. $\lambda_{1}\lambda_{2}>0$ and the sign of $k$ is opposite to this of $\lambda_{1}$ it is an ellipse
2. $\lambda_{1}\lambda_{2}>0$ and the sign of $k$ is same to this of $\lambda_{1}$ it is an empty set
3. $\lambda_{1}\lambda_{2}>0$ and $k=0$ it is a point
4. $\lambda_{1}\lambda_{2}>0$ and $k\neq 0$ it is an hyperbola
5. $\lambda_{1}\lambda_{2}>0$ and $k=0$ it is two straight lines

But (1) can be (4) and (5) can be (3)

Comment: eigenvalues in $(4)$ and $(5)$ must have opposite algebraic signs, so $\lambda_1\lambda_2<0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As serg_1 notes, two of the relation signs are not OK. Correct statements are:

1. $\lambda_{1}\lambda_{2}>0$ and the sign of $k$ is opposite to this of $\lambda_{1}$ it is an ellipse
2. $\lambda_{1}\lambda_{2}>0$ and the sign of $k$ is same to this of $\lambda_{1}$ it is an empty set
3. $\lambda_{1}\lambda_{2}>0$ and $k=0$ it is a point
4. $\lambda_{1}\lambda_{2}<0$[** N.B. "$<$"] and $k\neq 0$ it is an hyperbola
5. $\lambda_{1}\lambda_{2}<0$[** N.B. "$<$"] and $k=0$ it is two straight lines